# What is the best design pattern between BLoC, MVVM, MVC for Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, model-view-controller, mvvm, web-applications, bloc

I'm going to develop a management app for a company in Flutter and since I never worked with this framework i was looking for the best practices and desin patterns to use.

The app will be about employes management for a company. The main features will be:

- The management of the employes profiles;
- The possibility to upload documents directly in the app;
- Create online quiz for the employes in trainership;
  I'm struggling to choose the right design pattern. Usually for the frontend i use either the MVC or MVVM, but since this is my first Flutter app i made some researches and find out that one of the best pattern for Flutter is BLoC. I already tried to implement a simple app to try this pattern and i understood the way it works, but since I'm a noob in Flutter i was looking for some advices from someon who is more expert than me.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: still it depend, Since BLOC have a good business logic and easy to understand, its either MVC or MVVM but the most part is that is were you are at most comfortable with on that point you have a fast pace developing it since you know both patterns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best practices and design patterns to use it is TTD
it helps you to Keeping your code clean and tested
on the other hand, larger projects start falling apart when you mix the business logic everywhere. Even state management patterns like BLoC are not sufficient in themselves to allow for easily extendable codebase.
to get more information about TTD you can look to this tutorial in this link : https://resocoder.com/2019/08/27/flutter-tdd-clean-architecture-course-1-explanation-project-structure/

Comment: Thanks Muhammad I knew TDD but I thought it was more a developing strategy and not a design pattern, but the tutorial you linked seems really useful, so I'll read it and see if it fits good with my project. Thank you.